# Setting private variables using a getter

Tags: c++, getter-setter

What's the need for a separate get and set function if it's possible to combine them, like this:

```
class A {
private:
    int var = 0;
public:
    int& getset(){ return var; };
};

int main()
{
  A a = A();
  a.getset() = 4;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << a.getset() << "!\n";
}
```

I'm assuming there's something I've overlooked, but in case this is not a good idea; why is it possible to access private members this way?

Comment: getset?? please use another name for that....

Comment: your getset is breaking the capsuling giving you access to the private member variable ***var***

Comment: Because it's not obvious (IMHO) and because if you need to do something inside the setter you can't. Also, at this point, I'd just make `var` public and be done with it

Comment: The code you posted is not OOP. It's procedural thinking and coding, masqueraded as OOP by using classes. Make your `main()` look like `int main() { A a(4); a.greet(); }` and you'll start having some OOP in this code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for getters and setters at all: just make the variable public.

```
class A {
public:
    int var = 0;
};
```

If you want to hide implementation details, then the idea is that the getter is `const` while the setter is not. So they must be different functions

```
class A{
public:
    int getValue() const;
    int setValue(int new_value); // returns old value
private:
    /* implementation details: Value may be encoded other than in a simple variable */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need in any checks of values, than you should replace `class` to `struct` and remove unnecessary method:

```
struct A {
    int var = 0;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.var = 4;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << a.var << "!\n";
}
```

But if you need in more difficult logic and some checks of var, than you should write separate setter and getter, not like yours. `getset()` is terrible idea, don't do it again.

Comment: I'm aware that there are better ways of to achieve my result, but I'm asking why it's even possible: In which cases would my example be useful?

Comment: It is possible to use by your way, but it is not good practice: this code is hard for reading and understanding, and create many possibilities for errors in future.
Try to avoid it :)

Comment: @FrankVel "_why it's even possible_" because trying to make it not possible would (almost certainly) needlessly over-complicate the language (if it could be done without breaking "legitimate" code). "_In which cases would my example be useful_" -- probably none: if for some obscure reason this type of access _were_ required, making the underlying variable public is a simpler, more obvious way of achieving it. Not everything that's _possible_ has to have a (legitimate) use.